# What could be the possible error if a shell script fails when it is added to crontab?

Tags: shell, unix, cron

I have a shell script that creates a text file with the data resulted by a sql query. It runs perfectly when I run it manually, but when the job is added to crontab, it fails as it is not able fetch few required parameters from a table in database. What are the things that change when we schedule the job using crontab?
[edit]
The script uses following function to execute a sql query that is passed as argument. when I run it manually, sql query that is passed is returning the desired value so script runs successfully. But when it is run via crontab, there is no data returned by the sql query hence script abnormally exits stating that required parameters are missing.

`try_sql_spool() {
    (
        sqlplus -SILENT /NOLOG @/dev/stdin << EndOfSQL
        WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT FAILURE
        WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT FAILURE
        CONNECT $USER/$PWD@$SID
        SET SERVEROUTPUT OFF;
        SET TERMOUT OFF
        SET TRIMSPOOL ON
        SET PAGESIZE 0
        SET LINESIZE 32767
        SET FEEDBACK OFF
        SET VERIFY OFF
        SET TAB OFF
        SPOOL /dev/stderr
        $1
        SPOOL OFF
EndOfSQL
    ) #3<&1 1<&2 2<&3 3<&-
}`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The user running it, maybe. You should post the script.

Comment: sorry for not posting the script. I don't think I am allowed to post it. Can you tell me with which user are the cron jobs run by default?

Comment: The user, the PATH and other environment variables.

Comment: the user the crontab belongs to. At least you should post your error message if any.

Comment: There is no error as such. The script is running ,but it stops as it is not able to get required parameters from database.  so I guess there is no issue with the user, but actual issue is that , at the beginning of the script there is a sql statement which fetches all the required parameters to run the job. So I suspect connection to data base is not happening when it is run via cron. but if i manually run it it gets all the required parameters from database.

Comment: I think you are going to either need to show us some code or at the very least show us more details about how you run the script by hand vs. what your crontob entry looks like.  We're not mind readers, and without some more information in your question we're just guessing.

Comment: Sorry for providing too less info. I have updated the post. Thanks for your replies and solutions in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answering own question:

Script was aborting when added to crontab because, user was switched and it could not spool `/dev/stderr` as new user didn't have write permission to `/dev/stderr` . so there was `O/S Message: Permission denied` error. so It could not fetch required data from data base.

Thanks all for your response.